# RedirectToAction encoding

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Just upgraded my ASP.NET MVC 1.0 app to 2.0. Where:

```
return RedirectToAction(book.Isbn + "?" + book.BookTitleAsUrl);
```

used to work fine in 1.0, it's now html encoding the ?.

Any ideas to fix this in 2.0?

Thanks
Nick

Answer (score 0):

I am using it like this where [controller name] is the function you want to call:

```
RedirectToAction([controller name] , new { isbn = book.Isbn, BookTitleAsUrl = book.BookTitleAsUrl})
```

Comment: Thanks for reply - that doesn't give the url as /books/0071496661?BookTitle though

Comment: Yea it wouldnt. It would work if you had a controller that took isbn and bool title as argument.

Comment: To get the URL you mention, you would have to configure the routing accordingly. If you replace isbn by id, you'll get the desired result. Or, you can change the route definition.